# Как эффективно использовать совместно shrinkdatabase, shrinkfile и rebuildindex?

Tags: sql-server

Как эффективно использовать совместно shrinkdatabase, shrinkfile и rebuildindex ?

Периодиески сталкиваюсь с пробемой, чтобы база и файлы базы разрастаются. Вместо того чтобы использовать свободное место внутри базы, сервер запрашивает увеличивает размер файла базы данных, а вместе с ним и свободное пространство.

Как решение на переодической основе делаю шринк shrinkfile и shrinkdatabase, но при этих операциях ухудшается показатель фрагментации индексов. И если индексы сильно дефрагментированы, то шринк может оставить 40% свободного места в файле, что очень много в абсолютных величинах.

Вопрос как эффективно добиться того, чтобы и размер файлов базы данных был минимален и при этом индексы были бы максимально фрагментированы ? После оптимизации, некоторые базы данных планируется переводить в режим READONLY для архива.

Answer (score 0):

Для БД, в которых регулярно происходят crud-процессы с той же периодичностью можно делать rebuild index и обновлять статистику с той же регулярностью, но в моменты минимальной нагрузки на сервер. Т.е. если данные в бд "льются" постоянно, то ребилд лучше делать ночью один раз в сутки после окончания crud-процессов. Шринковать файлы и бд раз в неделю/месяц, но только если есть необходимость.

**UPD**: Возможно я некорректно выразился (плохой из меня "объяснитель"). Ещё раз

1. При ребилде индекса - старый индекс удаляется - после **завершения** операции место не вырастет. Ребилд- очень "тяжёлая" операция. Ребилд лучше делать в моменты минимальной нагрузки.
2. Адекватная замена ребилду - реорганизация индекса. Реорганизацию можно запускать днём и перезапускать её (если она была по каким-то причинам отменена) вплоть до достижения оптимальной фрагментации.

Больше информации по оптимальному ребилду/реорганизации индексов, а так же способам оценки фрагментации индекса можно посмотреть на сайте [ms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15). Там, в принципе, все по полочкам и с примерами :-)

В этот раз я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Вопрос был про другое. Как добиться, чтобы база была минимального размера и при этом были индексы обновлены.

Comment: Ежесуточное перестроение индексов - плохая идея?

Comment: да. потому что перестроение индексов увеличивает базу. причем иногда значительно.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Сорри, но кажется ты не совсем понял задачу. Вопрос не стоит -когда делать ? и что использовать reindex или rebuild.

Comment: Мне аж ещё интереснее стало. Буду отвечать очевидными(во всяком случае для меня) ответами. 1. Минимальный размер БД достигается как минимум приведением всех сущностей к максимально-возможной и применимой в данном случае НФ.  2. Актуализация индексов происходит регулярно при добавлении/изменении полей, входящих в индекс. 3. В целях освобождения занимаемого удалёнными записями места проводится оптимизация этих индексов, баз данных и файлов. Периодичность и способы оптимизации выбираются исходя из конкретной ситуации и задачи. 4. Вы ко мне на "ты"? С чего бы вдруг?

Comment: У меня есть таблица на 200 миллионов строк в базе данных. Занимает порядка 2 терабайт вместе с индексами.  Цель максимально ужать таблицу и индексы баз сильного ущерба в произвоительности поиска по таблице.  Базу планируется после сжатия и оптимизации перевести в режим readonly.